# Remove User from ACLs for a specific Directory

Tags: centos, setfacl

CentOS release 5.10.

```
getfacl --omit-header Shared/
user::rws
user:foo:rw
group::rw
mask:rw
```

I want to remove `user:foo:rw` from this entry.

`setfacl -m user:foo:0` simply removes permissions.

```
getfacl --omit-header Shared/
user::rws
user:foo:---
group::rw
mask:rw
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `setfacl -x user:foo Shared/`

`-m` just removes the permissions whereas `-x` removes the user.